# Failed to run VirtualBox on macOS 11 Big Sur

Tags: virtualbox, big-sur

I got this error when started a VM:

[image]

Comment: I assume you are running VBox **ON** the developer only beta of macOS 11? Note that this is a *developer* beta and these kind of things are expected. your best bet is to post this to the VBox forums as it is probably not (yet?) compatible with macOS 11.

Comment: You're correct Steve

Comment: There's also no actual question here.

Comment: I see the comment stating there is no question here as constructive criticism.  It is site policy for questions to be clear and get edited if needed. This is clearly a statement and not a question as written in the first version. I appreciate there’s an answer but to be reopened for more answers, an edit  clarify the question may be needed.

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask on how to write good questions.

Answer (score 8):

#### Big Sur is a *developer* beta, not a public release beta.

The difference being is that it's released to software developers so they have a relatively decent platform to begin work on getting their applications compatible with the new release of macOS.  It's not meant for end users to gain access to the bleeding edge of macOS tech because you want the latest and greatest features.

#### Report it!

You've gotten an error when trying to run VBox on Big Sur.  It's not ideal, but completely expected.  This is something you want to search for as an issue in [Oracle's Bug Tracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/report/11); if it doesn't exist, you should probably report it.

#### Testing is encouraged!

If you've decided to install Big Sur (or whatever the latest build is for future readers) on a *production* machine, I highly advise you to rethink that.  By "production," I mean one you rely on for work.  It's the machine you turn on to get your work done that gets you paid so you can keep the lights turned on.  A Beta version can work just fine and a subsequent release can break things to the point where you're dead in the water.

Install it on a test Mac.  It could be a cheap Mac mini or even a broken LCD, busted keyboard or dead battery MacBook laptop.  You just want something inexpensive you can try out the new features on.  This would be my recommendation.

If that's not possible, create a second (or third, or n<sup>th</sup>) boot volume so that you can manually boot into the new OS, test and play to your hearts content and when you need to get back to work on a stable version of macOS, your original install is still there.  Remember to make copious backups.

Comment: Actually I think this might not be a bug. Big Sur will completely disallow most 3rd party kexts. The issue is that Virtualbox heavily relies on its kexts for core functionality. I see no fast way for them to work around this as the only option is to use userland MacOS APIs - e.g. vmnet for virtual networks and hypervisor.framework for virtualization.