# Wifi dongle stopped working as soon a I upgraded to MacOS Big Sur 11 version

Tags: mac, wifi

My wifi dongle is not working on Big Sur. Whenever I tried to install the software that came with the wifi dongle, I get a message that the drive is incompatible. I was using a Wifi dongle from this company called Cuddy and when I contacted them, they said they are not sure when are they going to have a compatible driver for the same.

I found a similar post related to this over [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396024/macos-big-sur-cannot-use-wifi-adapter-device?newreg=2a597f0b4c5b47c0a4c8d11345cdf53d) when someone faced similar issue when Big sur was in beta phase.

And I was looking at `Gummibando's` answer where he mentioned the following:

> While macOS 11 is in development, you can enable the loading of deprecated KEXTs by disabling SIP. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11-beta-release-notes (Deprecations).

However, the link is not working anymore. Any other solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

While Apple hasn't realeased an official date for when third party kexts, they have been phasing them out for over a year now and over time the list of depreciated kexts is growing.

For now I believe that you can boot into recovery mode using Command and R, and then running `csrutil disable` in the terminal to disable SIP.

This is more like a temporary hotfix than a solution and I would advise getting a new dongle if your manufacturer does not keep up.

Comment: What does `csrutil disable` command do? I couldn't find any manufacture supporting MacOS 11 version and later releases.